# PostgreSQL - index on key

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, unique-constraint

I am wondering what the (side-) effects are if you create an index on a column/columns which is/are already covered by a unique consraint.

```
drop table if exists person;
create table person
(
    a   integer     not null,
    b   integer     not null,

    unique(a,b)
);
```

Here, a unique key constraint is put on `a,b`. I understood that this internally makes two indices: one on `a` and another on `a,b`.

Now I create two indices:

```
create index on person(a);
create index on person(a,b);
```

What is the effect of this?

Comment: No, the unique constraint creates a single unique index on (a,b).

Have you tried creating the extra indexes, to see if PostgreSQL allows it?

Comment: You don't need the indexes, the constraint creates a unique index on (a,b). (in some cases an extra index on (b,a) could be indicated)

Comment: @joop What do you mean with 'indicated'?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes, PostgreSQL allows it.

Comment: @JadeDezo: this kind of structure occurs often in *junction tables* , such as `table marriage( person1 integer NOT NULL references persons(id), person2 integer NOT NULL references persons(id) , PRIMARY KEY (person1,person2) );` In such a case an extra index om (person2,person1) can be helpful in supporting the FK constraints.

Comment: @joop Thanks, got you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understood that this internally makes two indices: one on a and another on a,b

Nope, this (`unique(a,b)`) internally creates just one index - the seccond one on  (a,b)

As far as side effects of `create index on person(a,b)` is concearned. It's "only" redundancy which will:

- decrease performance of opprations which are maintaining idexes such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `REINDEX`, `VACUUM FULL` etc.
- increase disk space used by realation (index is datastructure which must be stored on disk)
- there's no gain really since query planner may used one or anathor index depending on each execution

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll remove my comment :)

Comment: No problem:) I delete my answer to your comment and update my answer to by more straightforward:)

Answer (score 1):

> I understood that this internally makes two indices: one on a and another on a,b.

No, the unique index on (a,b) is created. After creating the two indexes you'll have three indexes:

```
"person_a_b_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (a, b)
"person_a_b_idx" btree (a, b)
"person_a_idx" btree (a)
```

The first and the second overlap and one of them will not be used.

Comment: I understand that the first and the second overlap. But isn't the third one also redundant, as a btree on `a,b` can be used for lookups on just `a`?

Comment: Yes, both additional indexes are redundant.

Comment: @JadeDezo, yes, index on `(a,b)` can be used for lookups on just `a`. But, if the query needs to read just `a` without `b` it could help to have an additional index just on `a`. Index just on `a` takes less bytes on disk than index on `(a,b)`, so it is faster to read. (Of course, extra index means extra overhead for updates and extra disk space.) @klin, my point is that additional index on `a` is not completely redundant.